# Build errors after adding SQLite data source

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sqlite, debugging, datasource

I have a brand new project, that I am playing around with to learn how to add
datasets to WPF form controls. Whenever i create the new project, with all default settings(WPF application), I can build it and run it with the default window just fine.
However When i add a new Data Source, which is an SQLite database that is sitting OUTSIDE of the project folder, and in my documents folder, it has build errors, and claims that the .EXE file doesn't exist in the bin/Debug folder.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what these build errors are. Wait... I've got it! You could tell us.  I can't believe noone thought of that earlier.

Comment: Also, why is the data file outside the project anyway? The fact that it is going to be outside the program folder after deployment isn't really a reason, because you simply change the connection string in the config file when you deploy.

Comment: My apologies. There werent any actual exceptions, but I did receive an error that there was no .EXE file found in the bin/Debug, which is essentially useless I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was using the SQLite provider from VB.Net 4.5 while the project was built under 4.6
This didn't raise as an error, but as a "Warning", which I tend to overlook sometimes. I changed the project build version and everything works fine now.